# BASH Как изменить значение переменной если изменилось значение переменной внутри нее

Tags: bash

Как изменить значение переменной если изменилось значение переменной внутри нее?

Написан парсер на bash, который выбирает значения до тех пор, пока значение переменной не будет пустым. Он отрабатывает корректно. Вопрос в правильности написания. Правильно ли так передавать новое значение переменной `x` или есть иные способы? Можно ли как-то сделать чтобы значение `x` автоматом обновлялось при изменении `c`?

```
#!/bin/bash
c=1
x=$(xmllint --xpath "//Данные[$c]" /root/xml/uc.xml)
while [ -n "$x" ]; do
let "c++"
x=$(xmllint --xpath "//Данные[$c]" /root/xml/uc.xml)
done
```

Comment: Непонятный вопрос. В переменной нет никакой другой переменной. Там лежит значение вычисленное в момент присваивания

Comment: @Alexey Ten Спасибо большое за ваш комментарий! Без иронии) Полистал еще гугл и нашел то, что было нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо! Вот что я хотел получить и получил. Помогло использование функции.

```
#!/bin/bash
c=1
x () { y=$(xmllint --xpath "//Данные[$c]" /root/xml/uc.xml);}
while x; do
if [ -n "$y" ]; then
let "c++"
fi; done
```

или вот так

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=1;; c++ )); do
x=$(xmllint --xpath "//Данные[$c]" /root/xml/uc.xml) 
if [ -n "$x" ]; then
else
break
fi; done
```